# Embedded RTOS producer and consumer with many types of messages

Tags: c, multithreading, embedded, freertos, rtos

Many RTOS message passing examples show a producer generating something as simple as an int32 and a consumer reading it. This is simple since you always know what type and therefore what size will come out of the queue (or other message passing buffer).

Consider the case of an RTOS thread which reads data from a GPS. A GPS has potentially many types of messages. You can't guarantee when a message will arrive, the order of the messages, or the size of the message. Each message will have many field, and each message could be represented as a struct.

This GPS handling producer RTOS thread would ideally parse the data stream in, and then pass the data out so that a consumer thread can easily read GPS data.

Assume FreeRTOS or CMSIS RTOS. How could this arrangement best be set up? Which primitives would be used? At a fundamental level, what I'm looking for is a clean way to pass several different types of different sized structs out of a producer thread and read them in a consumer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider using a queue of pointers to messages, rather that a queue of messages themselves.  That way each item on the queue is a fixed size (size of a pointer) regardless of the message.

The technique does require careful resource management to ensure the message is not modified, deleted or reused before the receiver has finished with it. You need a allocate-enqueue-dequeue-deallocate mechanism.

For example, given:

```
enum eMessageType
{ AType, 
  BType
};

struct GenericMessage
{
    eMessageType type;
    char payload[0] ; // Note GCC zero-length array extension
};

struct A { struct GenericMessage, 
           uint32_t foo;
         };

struct B { struct GenericMessage,
           uint8_t bar;
         };
```

Then the sender might have something like (pseudo-code) :

```
 struct A* messageA = allocateMessageA( AType, 0x12345678 ) ;     
 struct B* messageB = allocateMessageB{ BType, 0x12 } ;

 sendGeneric( genericQ, messageA ) ;     
 sendGeneric( genericQ, messageB ) ;
```

and the receiver:

```
 struct GenericMessage* message_ptr = receiveGeneric( genericQ ) ;
 switch( message_ptr->type )
 {
    case AType:
    {
        struct A* = (struct A*)message_ptr ;
        uint32_t payload = message_ptr->payload ;
        ...
        deallocateMessageA( message_ptr ) ;
    }
    break;

    case BType:
    {
        struct B* = (struct B*)message_ptr ;
        uint8_t payload = message_ptr->payload ;
        ...
        deallocateMessageB( message_ptr ) ;
    }
}
```

The details of the allocation/deallocation functions I have not defined.  A simple method is to use fixed-block memory pools.  If your RTOS does not provide these, a simple implementation is to have queues of pointers to messages in a pool, one queue/pool per message type.  To allocate you simply take a pointer from the relevant message pool by taking a message off the queue, and deallocate by returning the pointer to the queue.

Note that some RTOS allow variable length messages to be sent directly - in embOS for example you can allocate a memory pool for the queue, and specify the length when sending rather than when creating the queue. The receiver however must be able to receive the largest possible message.

Answer (score 4):

The FreeRTOS documentation discusses the problem in conjunction with QueueSets. (See https://www.freertos.org/Pend-on-multiple-rtos-objects.html in section "Alternatives to Using Queue Sets").
Basically, the idea is to have an enum to identify different types of messages in a buffer.

For your buffer type, you could use a combination of an enum and a union of structs.

```
struct A {uint32_t foo;};
struct B {uint8_t bar;};
enum T {AType, BType};

struct GenericMessage{
    T type;
    union{
        struct A a;
        struct B b;
    };
};
```

Then you can distinguish between the messages as follows:

```
void handleGenericMessage(struct GenericMessage* msg){
    switch(msg->type){
        case AType:
            handleA(msg->a);
            break;
        case BType:
            handleB(msg->b);
            break;
}
```

Comment: I suppose this means that sizeof(GenericMessage) is the size of the largest struct in the union? I guess it's not a dealbreaker, but was hoping there was something cleaner.

Comment: @chris12892 Yes, it is the size of the largest struct + the size of the enum element. Cleaner by which means? You could of course use C++ with runtime type information (RTTI) to upcast, but I guess you better avoid the RTTI overhead.

Comment: @chris12892 ,  it is memory vs runtime overhead selection: if the possible structs are known and you can live with allocating large enough queue - there is nothing unclean with using unions. If you have enough mcu power to allocate and free message body - use pointers to data instead of sending the data, but be aware of the mcu overhead of fragmentation, or use multiple allocation pools